# objective-c nscomparisonresult works wrongly?

Tags: objective-c, string, comparison, string-comparison

It somehow does not work with Scandinavian alphabets.

When I enter @"å", and there are two strings that "sandwich" that search word;
one string is starting with "ø" which is lower than "å" and another string that starts with "å". However this comparison code returns SOMETIMES correct, SOMETIMES wrong result, even though I used same search string, i.e. @"å" over and over again. Is there something I have overlooked?

EDIT: sorry it should be two different compStrings (as in my code), I forgot to put number 2 as suffix.

**compString2 means the second string that begins with å.
compString is the one that begins with ø.**

I need to compare search string with two strings to find out whether it is between these two strings or not.

Let me formulate it in a better way, for those that don't know Scandinavian alphabets, å is like c and ø is like b, and if search string is c, then it must be between b and c, right?

Here is my code:

```
NSString *compString = [array objectAtIndex:i]; //i is an incremental number from a for-loop

//norwegian language
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"no_NO"];


if([searchString compare:compString2
                 options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSAnchoredSearch)
                   range:range
                  locale:locale] == (NSOrderedAscending | NSOrderedSame)) {

    if([searchString compare:compString
                     options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSAnchoredSearch) 
                       range:range
                      locale:locale] == NSOrderedDescending) {

        NSLog(@"found");

    }
}
```

FINAL-EDIT:

I found the problem. The solution is simple. NEVER DO what I wrote bitwise OR operator "|" or plain OR operator "||".

```
if([searchString compare:compString
options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
range:range locale:locale] == NSOrderedAscending ||
 [searchString
 compare:compString
 options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
range:range locale:locale] == NSOrderedSame)
```

meaning **searchString <= compString**

```
if([searchString
   compare:compString
   options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
    range:range locale:locale] == NSOrderedDescending)
```

meaning **searchString > compString**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why is one `if` inside the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use `NSOrderedAscending` and `NSOrderedSame` as bits of a bit field in the first comparison result evaluation, since you do not get the logical (!) `OR` that you probably want.

Try this instead in your first `if ()`:

```
if([searchString compare:compString2
                 options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSAnchoredSearch)
                   range:range
                  locale:locale] != NSOrderedDescending) {

    /* ... */

}
```

Comment: I tried this one too, but it gave same result. Sometimes it matches, sometimes not. I use same comparing strings and search string always and it is unbelievable that it gives varying result. Perhaps it has something to do with iOS7 or Xcode 5.1? Perhaps nslocale is not always dominating?

Comment: What about the `range` variable? Also, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) explains that `options` should be "any of the following using a C bitwise OR operator: `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch`, `NSLiteralSearch`, `NSNumericSearch`". In other words, it does not mention `NSAnchoredSearch` explicitly. Could you please post code that can be compiled and run?

Comment: do you mean that I should give nil as argument to parameter "range"? I'm aware of it, strangely it searches better with NSAnchoredSearch. Now I have removed it, but the result is still same. The code is long... It is inside textDidChange-method for object search bar. I have only one TableView with one search bar.

Comment: No, I don't recommend you give `nil` as parameter `range`! It might well be that your code is long. In order to locate the error, you should provide [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, have to tried to inspect your algorithm with breakpoints and the debugger or `NSLog`s to confirm that it really is the comparisons that do not work?

Comment: yes, I confirm that it is only comparison that is the problem. However, I wonder if there is another way to compare?

Comment: Could you post the values of `searchString`, `compString` and `compString2` that cause problems, including the expected result and the result or varying results, maybe right in your question, instead of the line with the `objectAtIndex`?

Comment: On my machine, targeting OS X SDK 10.9, there is no locale "no_NO" in the array returned by `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`. However, the pointer returned by `[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"no_NO"];` is not `nil` either. Does it work with `@"nn_NO"` or `@"nb_NO"`?

Comment: I found this: http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php I really need nb, not nn, but it doesn't change anything. However, perhaps you could provide me an example on how nscomparisonresult works when compString is build and compString is car and the search string is "c"?

Comment: I found what was wrong. Your guess was almost right. Will update with new edit soon.